# In django , how to develop this particular relationship in a model?

Tags: django

Class1's id should be the foreign key and also the primary key of Class2 . How to set up this relationship ?

I do know , this is a basic question . But I am a bit confused as to how to go about it . Class1 has a One to One relationhip with Class2 , Class3 and henceforth . So should that also be mentioned in the model of Class2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to have the PK of `Class1` be both the PK *and* FK of `Class2` is for `Class2` to derive from `Class1` (`class Class2(Class1):`). But this has [other implications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), and you need to sit down and decide if this is really what you want.

Comment: If I don't want it as the primary key , and want it just as the foreign key . Then would the normal definition that is ForeignKey(Class1) would do ?

Comment: If you want multiple `Class2`s per `Class1`, yes. Otherwise a `OneToOneField` would be the way to go.